# Unable to understand error "SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event ..."

Tags: apache-spark

### The issue

I'd like to know if anyone has a magic method to avoid such messages in Spark logs:

```
2015-08-30 19:30:44 ERROR LiveListenerBus:75 - SparkListenerBus has already
stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerExecutorMetricsUpdate(41,WrappedArray())
```

After further investigations, I understand that `LiveListenerBus` extends `AsynchronousListenerBus`. And thus, at some point, `.stop()` method is called. Then, messages that might be sent/received will be dropped and remain unprocessed. Basically, some `SparkListenerExecutorMetricsUpdate` messages are unfortunately not received yet, and once they are, they become dropped to nowhere.

This doesn't look critical since `SparkListenerExecutorMetricsUpdate` just correspond to *Periodic updates from executors.*

What is embarrassing is that I absolutely don't understand why this happens and nothings refers to this issue. Note that this is totally non-deterministic and I can't reproduce this, probably due to the asynchronous nature and my lack of understand on how/when `stop()` is supposed to be called.

### About the running code

A tight sample:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val metricsMap = Metrics.values.toSeq.map(
    v => v -> sc.accumulator(0, v.toString)
).toMap
val outFiles = sc.textFile(outPaths)
```

And there's no other reference to `sc` or a `SparkContent` instance.

Comment: Dealing with this now :(

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure out the reason of that error?

Answer (score 3):

This ticket might be related.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12009

The message seems to indicate yarn allocation failure after sparkcontext stop.

---

Sorry for unclear comment.

The main reason seems that there is some interval between AM's shutdown event and executors stop all.
So, AM tries to reallocate after executors stop.

As Saisai said below,

> A interesting thing is that AM is shutting down at time 2015-11-26,03:05:16, but YarnAllocator still request 13 executors after 11 seconds. Looks like AM is not exited so fast, that's why YarnAllocator is still requesting new containers. Normally if AM is exited as fast as it receive disconnected message, there will be not time for container requesting for YarnAllocator.

I have come across similar logs near finishing spark context sometimes.
In my case, this ticket seems to be answer.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.