# Spark: ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped

Tags: apache-spark

I am getting this error when submitting Spark jobs both in client or cluster mode? Basically I am trying to merge thousands of event files into one file using `sc.repartition`. At the end I am able to see that all the files containing events are merged to a single file. In the logs/console I observe hundreds of error lines as below

> ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerExecutorMetricsUpdate(67,WrappedArray())
>   18/01/20 18:21:01 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerExecutorMetricsUpdate(32,WrappedArray())

I am using Azure HDInsight spark cluster 3.5, which has Spark 2.0.

As per the thread [Unable to understand error "SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340639). it looks like it should have been solved in Spark 2.0, but I see it still persists. Could there be any workaround?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure out the reason of that error?