# Spark ERROR scheduler.LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped

Tags: apache-spark

I ran into a problem of spark, which is very strange. Could anyone help?
Thanks in advance.
Code is here:

```
import re, sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, HiveContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
import time
import urllib2
import socket
import base64
from operator import add
from subprocess import call


def transToTimeStamp(time_bigint):
  return time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", time.localtime(float(time_bigint)))


def getImageData(url):
  try:
     return base64.b64encode(urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=10).read())
  except Exception, e:
     print('Exception: ' + e.message)
     return ""

if __name__ == '__main__':
  spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .appName('uniq_xxx')\
    .config('spark.sql.warehouse.dir','spark-warehouse')\
    .enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
  sql = 'select id, image, time from tabletest where time > 1506787200'
  df = spark.sql(sql)
  print df.count()
  out_path = "/user/test/images3/"
  myudf = udf(transToTimeStamp, StringType())
  img_udf = udf(getImageData, StringType())
  new_df = df.withColumn('dayaaa', myudf(df.post_time)).withColumn('img_data', img_udf(df.image2)).drop('image2').drop('post_time')
  new_df.write.partitionBy('dayaaa').mode('overwrite').save(out_path)
  spark.stop()
```

Data is about 4900w row.

Error is:

> 18/01/19 21:52:14 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 1 failed: save at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0, took 8083.693827 s
>   18/01/19 21:52:14 ERROR scheduler.LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerExecutorMetricsUpdate(1,WrappedArray((69,2,0,Vector(AccumulableInfo(1531,Some(internal.metrics.executorDeserializeTime),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1532,Some(internal.metrics.executorDeserializeCpuTime),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1533,Some(internal.metrics.executorRunTime),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1534,Some(internal.metrics.executorCpuTime),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1535,Some(internal.metrics.resultSize),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1536,Some(internal.metrics.jvmGCTime),Some(594),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1537,Some(internal.metrics.resultSerializationTime),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1538,Some(internal.metrics.memoryBytesSpilled),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1539,Some(internal.metrics.diskBytesSpilled),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1540,Some(internal.metrics.peakExecutionMemory),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1541,Some(internal.metrics.updatedBlockStatuses),Some([(broadcast_4_piece0,BlockStatus(StorageLevel(memory, 1 replicas),41884,0)), (broadcast_4,BlockStatus(StorageLevel(memory, deserialized, 1 replicas),107120,0)), (broadcast_3_piece0,BlockStatus(StorageLevel(memory, 1 replicas),27122,0)), (broadcast_3,BlockStatus(StorageLevel(memory, deserialized, 1 replicas),408720,0))]),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1542,Some(internal.metrics.shuffle.read.remoteBlocksFetched),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1543,Some(internal.metrics.shuffle.read.localBlocksFetched),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1544,Some(internal.metrics.shuffle.read.remoteBytesRead),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1545,Some(internal.metrics.shuffle.read.localBytesRead),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1546,Some(internal.metrics.shuffle.read.fetchWaitTime),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1547,Some(internal.metrics.shuffle.read.recordsRead),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1548,Some(internal.metrics.shuffle.write.bytesWritten),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1549,Some(internal.metrics.shuffle.write.recordsWritten),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1550,Some(internal.metrics.shuffle.write.writeTime),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1551,Some(internal.metrics.input.bytesRead),Some(6154349),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1552,Some(internal.metrics.input.recordsRead),Some(532922),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1553,Some(internal.metrics.output.bytesWritten),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1554,Some(internal.metrics.output.recordsWritten),Some(0),None,true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(1530,Some(number of output rows),Some(532922),None,true,true,Some(sql)), AccumulableInfo(1528,Some(duration total (min, med, max)),Some(-1),None,true,true,Some(sql)), AccumulableInfo(1529,Some(number of output rows),Some(372600),None,true,true,Some(sql)), AccumulableInfo(0,None,Some([]),None,false,false,None), AccumulableInfo(1527,Some(duration total (min, med, max)),Some(-1),None,true,true,Some(sql))))))
>   18/01/19 21:52:14 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 2 (save at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) failed in 8083.670 s due to Stage cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
>   18/01/19 21:52:14 ERROR scheduler.LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerStageCompleted(org.apache.spark.scheduler.StageInfo@5663383a)
>   18/01/19 21:52:14 ERROR datasources.FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null.
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 1 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:808)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:806)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:78)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:806)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onStop(DAGScheduler.scala:1668)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.stop(EventLoop.scala:83)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$8.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1826)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1283)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1825)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:581)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:216)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1951)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
>           at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:127)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:101)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure out the reason of that error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to understand error "SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340639/unable-to-understand-error-sparklistenerbus-has-already-stopped-dropping-event)