# Converting json strings to dataframe in spark in Python

Tags: json, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

(Apache Spark Version 2.3.1 on Databricks)

Hello I have a JSON dump that looks like this

```
[{"standings": {"visitorteam_position": 1, "localteam_position": 1}, "season_id": 892, "pitch": null, "commentaries": null, "id": 10342083, "venue_id": 273277, "formations": {"localteam_formation": null, "visitorteam_formation": null}, "aggregate_id": null, "round_id": null, "visitorteam_id": 18647, "winning_odds_calculated": false, "deleted": false, "coaches": {"localteam_coach_id": 472158, "visitorteam_coach_id": 474616}, "attendance": null, "scores": {"ft_score": null, "visitorteam_score": 0, "et_score": null, "localteam_pen_score": null, "visitorteam_pen_score": null, "localteam_score": 0, "ht_score": null}, "referee_id": 18783, "stage_id": 1728, "weather_report": null, "league_id": 732, "localteam_id": 15251, "time": {"status": "NS", "starting_at": {"date": "2018-07-06", "date_time": "2018-07-06 14:00:00", "timezone": "UTC", "timestamp": 1530885600, "time": "14:00:00"}, "extra_minute": null, "injury_time": null, "second": null, "added_time": null, "minute": null}, "group_id": null}, {"standings": {"visitorteam_position": 1, "localteam_position": 1}, "season_id": 892, "pitch": null, "commentaries": null, "id": 10344350, "venue_id": 8869, "formations": {"localteam_formation": null, "visitorteam_formation": null}, "aggregate_id": null, "round_id": null, "visitorteam_id": 18743, "winning_odds_calculated": false, "deleted": false, "coaches": {"localteam_coach_id": 474720, "visitorteam_coach_id": 474796}, "attendance": null, "scores": {"ft_score": null, "visitorteam_score": 0, "et_score": null, "localteam_pen_score": null, "visitorteam_pen_score": null, "localteam_score": 0, "ht_score": null}, "referee_id": 16781, "stage_id": 1728, "weather_report": null, "league_id": 732, "localteam_id": 18704, "time": {"status": "NS", "starting_at": {"date": "2018-07-06", "date_time": "2018-07-06 18:00:00", "timezone": "UTC", "timestamp": 1530900000, "time": "18:00:00"}, "extra_minute": null, "injury_time": null, "second": null, "added_time": null, "minute": null}, "group_id": null}]
```

I am trying to convert it to a dataframe directly from a variable instead of a JSON file upload; mainly because I get the JSON data from a GET request to an API.

This is my code for conversion -

```
countries = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(json.dumps(ts)).show(false)
```

Gives me this error, please point me in the right direction. I checked around, but I just see solutions for Scala. Looking for a Python fix to the same.

> IllegalArgumentException: u'java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path
>   in absolute URI:
>   "[{\"standings\":%20%7B%5C%22visitorteam_position%5C%22:%201,%20%5C%22localteam_position%5C%22:%201%7D,%20%5C%22season_id%5C%22:%20892,%20%5C%22pitch%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22commentaries%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22id%5C%22:%2010342083,%20%5C%22venue_id%5C%22:%20273277,%20%5C%22formations%5C%22:%20%7B%5C%22localteam_formation%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22visitorteam_formation%5C%22:%20null%7D,%20%5C%22aggregate_id%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22round_id%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22visitorteam_id%5C%22:%2018647,%20%5C%22winning_odds_calculated%5C%22:%20false,%20%5C%22deleted%5C%22:%20false,%20%5C%22coaches%5C%22:%20%7B%5C%22localteam_coach_id%5C%22:%20472158,%20%5C%22visitorteam_coach_id%5C%22:%20474616%7D,%20%5C%22attendance%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22scores%5C%22:%20%7B%5C%22ft_score%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22visitorteam_score%5C%22:%200,%20%5C%22et_score%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22localteam_pen_score%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22visitorteam_pen_score%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22localteam_score%5C%22:%200,%20%5C%22ht_score%5C%22:%20null%7D,%20%5C%22referee_id%5C%22:%2018783,%20%5C%22stage_id%5C%22:%201728,%20%5C%22weather_report%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22league_id%5C%22:%20732,%20%5C%22localteam_id%5C%22:%2015251,%20%5C%22time%5C%22:%20%7B%5C%22status%5C%22:%20%5C%22NS%5C%22,%20%5C%22starting_at%5C%22:%20%7B%5C%22date%5C%22:%20%5C%222018-07-06%5C%22,%20%5C%22date_time%5C%22:%20%5C%222018-07-06%2014:00:00%5C%22,%20%5C%22timezone%5C%22:%20%5C%22UTC%5C%22,%20%5C%22timestamp%5C%22:%201530885600,%20%5C%22time%5C%22:%20%5C%2214:00:00%5C%22%7D,%20%5C%22extra_minute%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22injury_time%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22second%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22added_time%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22minute%5C%22:%20null%7D,%20%5C%22group_id%5C%22:%20null%7D,%20%7B%5C%22standings%5C%22:%20%7B%5C%22visitorteam_position%5C%22:%201,%20%5C%22localteam_position%5C%22:%201%7D,%20%5C%22season_id%5C%22:%20892,%20%5C%22pitch%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22commentaries%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22id%5C%22:%2010344350,%20%5C%22venue_id%5C%22:%208869,%20%5C%22formations%5C%22:%20%7B%5C%22localteam_formation%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22visitorteam_formation%5C%22:%20null%7D,%20%5C%22aggregate_id%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22round_id%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22visitorteam_id%5C%22:%2018743,%20%5C%22winning_odds_calculated%5C%22:%20false,%20%5C%22deleted%5C%22:%20false,%20%5C%22coaches%5C%22:%20%7B%5C%22localteam_coach_id%5C%22:%20474720,%20%5C%22visitorteam_coach_id%5C%22:%20474796%7D,%20%5C%22attendance%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22scores%5C%22:%20%7B%5C%22ft_score%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22visitorteam_score%5C%22:%200,%20%5C%22et_score%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22localteam_pen_score%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22visitorteam_pen_score%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22localteam_score%5C%22:%200,%20%5C%22ht_score%5C%22:%20null%7D,%20%5C%22referee_id%5C%22:%2016781,%20%5C%22stage_id%5C%22:%201728,%20%5C%22weather_report%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22league_id%5C%22:%20732,%20%5C%22localteam_id%5C%22:%2018704,%20%5C%22time%5C%22:%20%7B%5C%22status%5C%22:%20%5C%22NS%5C%22,%20%5C%22starting_at%5C%22:%20%7B%5C%22date%5C%22:%20%5C%222018-07-06%5C%22,%20%5C%22date_time%5C%22:%20%5C%222018-07-06%2018:00:00%5C%22,%20%5C%22timezone%5C%22:%20%5C%22UTC%5C%22,%20%5C%22timestamp%5C%22:%201530900000,%20%5C%22time%5C%22:%20%5C%2218:00:00%5C%22%7D,%20%5C%22extra_minute%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22injury_time%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22second%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22added_time%5C%22:%20null,%20%5C%22minute%5C%22:%20null%7D,%20%5C%22group_id%5C%22:%20null%7D%5D%22'

Output for

print(ts)

```
Out[45]: 
[{u'aggregate_id': None,
  u'attendance': None,
  u'coaches': {u'localteam_coach_id': 472158, u'visitorteam_coach_id': 474616},
  u'commentaries': None,
  u'deleted': False,
  u'formations': {u'localteam_formation': None,
   u'visitorteam_formation': None},
  u'group_id': None,
  u'id': 10342083,
  u'league_id': 732,
  u'localteam_id': 15251,
  u'pitch': None,
  u'referee_id': 18783,
  u'round_id': None,
  u'scores': {u'et_score': None,
   u'ft_score': None,
   u'ht_score': None,
   u'localteam_pen_score': None,
   u'localteam_score': 0,
   u'visitorteam_pen_score': None,
   u'visitorteam_score': 0},
  u'season_id': 892,
  u'stage_id': 1728,
  u'standings': {u'localteam_position': 1, u'visitorteam_position': 1},
  u'time': {u'added_time': None,
   u'extra_minute': None,
   u'injury_time': None,
   u'minute': None,
   u'second': None,
   u'starting_at': {u'date': u'2018-07-06',
    u'date_time': u'2018-07-06 14:00:00',
    u'time': u'14:00:00',
    u'timestamp': 1530885600,
    u'timezone': u'UTC'},
   u'status': u'NS'},
  u'venue_id': 273277,
  u'visitorteam_id': 18647,
  u'weather_report': None,
  u'winning_odds_calculated': False},
 {u'aggregate_id': None,
  u'attendance': None,
  u'coaches': {u'localteam_coach_id': 474720, u'visitorteam_coach_id': 474796},
  u'commentaries': None,
  u'deleted': False,
  u'formations': {u'localteam_formation': None,
   u'visitorteam_formation': None},
  u'group_id': None,
  u'id': 10344350,
  u'league_id': 732,
  u'localteam_id': 18704,
  u'pitch': None,
  u'referee_id': 16781,
  u'round_id': None,
  u'scores': {u'et_score': None,
   u'ft_score': None,
   u'ht_score': None,
   u'localteam_pen_score': None,
   u'localteam_score': 0,
   u'visitorteam_pen_score': None,
   u'visitorteam_score': 0},
  u'season_id': 892,
  u'stage_id': 1728,
  u'standings': {u'localteam_position': 1, u'visitorteam_position': 1},
  u'time': {u'added_time': None,
   u'extra_minute': None,
   u'injury_time': None,
   u'minute': None,
   u'second': None,
   u'starting_at': {u'date': u'2018-07-06',
    u'date_time': u'2018-07-06 18:00:00',
    u'time': u'18:00:00',
    u'timestamp': 1530900000,
    u'timezone': u'UTC'},
   u'status': u'NS'},
  u'venue_id': 8869,
  u'visitorteam_id': 18743,
  u'weather_report': None,
  u'winning_odds_calculated': False}]
```

print(json.dumps(ts))

```
Out[44]: '[{"standings": {"visitorteam_position": 1, "localteam_position": 1}, "season_id": 892, "pitch": null, "commentaries": null, "id": 10342083, "venue_id": 273277, "formations": {"localteam_formation": null, "visitorteam_formation": null}, "aggregate_id": null, "round_id": null, "visitorteam_id": 18647, "winning_odds_calculated": false, "deleted": false, "coaches": {"localteam_coach_id": 472158, "visitorteam_coach_id": 474616}, "attendance": null, "scores": {"ft_score": null, "visitorteam_score": 0, "et_score": null, "localteam_pen_score": null, "visitorteam_pen_score": null, "localteam_score": 0, "ht_score": null}, "referee_id": 18783, "stage_id": 1728, "weather_report": null, "league_id": 732, "localteam_id": 15251, "time": {"status": "NS", "starting_at": {"date": "2018-07-06", "date_time": "2018-07-06 14:00:00", "timezone": "UTC", "timestamp": 1530885600, "time": "14:00:00"}, "extra_minute": null, "injury_time": null, "second": null, "added_time": null, "minute": null}, "group_id": null}, {"standings": {"visitorteam_position": 1, "localteam_position": 1}, "season_id": 892, "pitch": null, "commentaries": null, "id": 10344350, "venue_id": 8869, "formations": {"localteam_formation": null, "visitorteam_formation": null}, "aggregate_id": null, "round_id": null, "visitorteam_id": 18743, "winning_odds_calculated": false, "deleted": false, "coaches": {"localteam_coach_id": 474720, "visitorteam_coach_id": 474796}, "attendance": null, "scores": {"ft_score": null, "visitorteam_score": 0, "et_score": null, "localteam_pen_score": null, "visitorteam_pen_score": null, "localteam_score": 0, "ht_score": null}, "referee_id": 16781, "stage_id": 1728, "weather_report": null, "league_id": 732, "localteam_id": 18704, "time": {"status": "NS", "starting_at": {"date": "2018-07-06", "date_time": "2018-07-06 18:00:00", "timezone": "UTC", "timestamp": 1530900000, "time": "18:00:00"}, "extra_minute": null, "injury_time": null, "second": null, "added_time": null, "minute": null}, "group_id": null}]'
```

Thanks in advance!

PS. - Here is the link on how to do it with Scala - http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#tab_scala_5

Comment: if ts is in the format as you have posted then (json.dumps(ts) would have string json with \n as `[{'aggregate_id': None,\n  'attendance': None,\n  'coaches':...` isn't that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said

> I am trying to convert it to a dataframe directly from a variable instead of a JSON file upload; mainly because I get the JSON data from a GET request to an API.

So I assume ts is a variable like

```
ts = """[{"standings": {"visitorteam_position": 1, "localteam_position": 1}, "season_id": 892, "pitch": null, "commentaries": null, "id": 10342083, "venue_id": 273277, "formations": {"localteam_formation": null, "visitorteam_formation": null}, "aggregate_id": null, "round_id": null, "visitorteam_id": 18647, "winning_odds_calculated": false, "deleted": false, "coaches": {"localteam_coach_id": 472158, "visitorteam_coach_id": 474616}, "attendance": null, "scores": {"ft_score": null, "visitorteam_score": 0, "et_score": null, "localteam_pen_score": null, "visitorteam_pen_score": null, "localteam_score": 0, "ht_score": null}, "referee_id": 18783, "stage_id": 1728, "weather_report": null, "league_id": 732, "localteam_id": 15251, "time": {"status": "NS", "starting_at": {"date": "2018-07-06", "date_time": "2018-07-06 14:00:00", "timezone": "UTC", "timestamp": 1530885600, "time": "14:00:00"}, "extra_minute": null, "injury_time": null, "second": null, "added_time": null, "minute": null}, "group_id": null}, {"standings": {"visitorteam_position": 1, "localteam_position": 1}, "season_id": 892, "pitch": null, "commentaries": null, "id": 10344350, "venue_id": 8869, "formations": {"localteam_formation": null, "visitorteam_formation": null}, "aggregate_id": null, "round_id": null, "visitorteam_id": 18743, "winning_odds_calculated": false, "deleted": false, "coaches": {"localteam_coach_id": 474720, "visitorteam_coach_id": 474796}, "attendance": null, "scores": {"ft_score": null, "visitorteam_score": 0, "et_score": null, "localteam_pen_score": null, "visitorteam_pen_score": null, "localteam_score": 0, "ht_score": null}, "referee_id": 16781, "stage_id": 1728, "weather_report": null, "league_id": 732, "localteam_id": 18704, "time": {"status": "NS", "starting_at": {"date": "2018-07-06", "date_time": "2018-07-06 18:00:00", "timezone": "UTC", "timestamp": 1530900000, "time": "18:00:00"}, "extra_minute": null, "injury_time": null, "second": null, "added_time": null, "minute": null}, "group_id": null}]"""
```

Now, `json.dumps(ts)` would give you a string and `.json(json.dumps(ts))` is treating `json.dumps(ts)` as a path and thats what the error message is suggesting you

> > IllegalArgumentException: u'java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: "[{\"standings\":%20%7B%5C%22visitorteam_position%5C%22:%201,%20%5C%22localteam_position%5C%22:%201%7D,%20%5C%22season_id%5C%22:%20892,%20%5C

And API documentation says the following

> > `.... :param path: string represents path to the JSON dataset, or a list of paths, or RDD of Strings storing JSON objects.   .......`

So if you want to use the variable `ts` then, as the API documenation says, you will have to convert the string `json.dumps(ts)` to `RDD` as

```
tsRDD = sc.parallelize([ts])
df = spark.read.option('multiline', "true").json(tsRDD)
```

which should give the correct dataframe

```
+------------+----------+----------------+------------+-------+----------+--------+--------+---------+------------+-----+----------+--------+------------+---------+--------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------------------+
|aggregate_id|attendance|coaches         |commentaries|deleted|formations|group_id|id      |league_id|localteam_id|pitch|referee_id|round_id|scores      |season_id|stage_id|standings|time                                                                    |venue_id|visitorteam_id|weather_report|winning_odds_calculated|
+------------+----------+----------------+------------+-------+----------+--------+--------+---------+------------+-----+----------+--------+------------+---------+--------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------------------+
|null        |null      |[472158, 474616]|null        |false  |[,]       |null    |10342083|732      |15251       |null |18783     |null    |[,,,, 0,, 0]|892      |1728    |[1, 1]   |[,,,,, [2018-07-06, 2018-07-06 14:00:00, 14:00:00, 1530885600, UTC], NS]|273277  |18647         |null          |false                  |
|null        |null      |[474720, 474796]|null        |false  |[,]       |null    |10344350|732      |18704       |null |16781     |null    |[,,,, 0,, 0]|892      |1728    |[1, 1]   |[,,,,, [2018-07-06, 2018-07-06 18:00:00, 18:00:00, 1530900000, UTC], NS]|8869    |18743         |null          |false                  |
+------------+----------+----------------+------------+-------+----------+--------+--------+---------+------------+-----+----------+--------+------------+---------+--------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------------------+

root
 |-- aggregate_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- attendance: string (nullable = true)
 |-- coaches: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- localteam_coach_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- visitorteam_coach_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- commentaries: string (nullable = true)
 |-- deleted: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- formations: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- localteam_formation: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- visitorteam_formation: string (nullable = true)
 |-- group_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- league_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- localteam_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- pitch: string (nullable = true)
 |-- referee_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- round_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- scores: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- et_score: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ft_score: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ht_score: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- localteam_pen_score: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- localteam_score: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- visitorteam_pen_score: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- visitorteam_score: long (nullable = true)
 |-- season_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- stage_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- standings: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- localteam_position: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- visitorteam_position: long (nullable = true)
 |-- time: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- added_time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- extra_minute: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- injury_time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- minute: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- second: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- starting_at: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- date_time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- timezone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- venue_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- visitorteam_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- weather_report: string (nullable = true)
 |-- winning_odds_calculated: boolean (nullable = true)
```

Or you can just save the variables in a file and use

```
df = spark.read.option('multiline', "true").json(path to the file)
```

which works as perfect as above suggestion

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Hi Ramesh, thanks a lot for your reply. I did try the serialize function but it returned corrupted data because i didn't add the square parentheses around ts as an argument. Is there a reason  we are doing that given that ts is already a stringified list of JSON objects?

Comment: I would need to see the datatype and data of ts. samples would do.

Comment: I have appended the data dump in the question above, could you please check?

Comment: if ts is in the format as you have posted then (json.dumps(ts) would have string json with \n as [{'aggregate_id': None,\n 'attendance': None,\n 'coaches':... isn't that so?

Comment: Somehow it doesn't show that way on Databricks output with the print function! Works as expected in the final output though.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan sir used your solution in scala " val df=spark.read.option("multiline", true).json(listRDD))" ,I am able to print the schema but throwing an error as I try to do df.show() ,error is ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerSQLExecutionStart

Comment: @experiment make sure there is no problem with you spark configuration and installation

Comment: @RameshMaharjan no sir ,I am able to show the other df but not the one when I am trying to load the json

Comment: search for exact solution in stackoverflow like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340639/unable-to-understand-error-sparklistenerbus-has-already-stopped-dropping-event if none of them works then you can post a new question. :)